# Selecting data from table with join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, outer-join

I have two tables and I am trying to get information with an outer left join.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sportjefit_user 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN vriend ON sportjefit_user.id = vriend.vriend2
```

and this result:
[image]

I only want the records where 'vriend1' or 'vriend2' is not 48

Can somebody please help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a [where clause](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp) which would map almost exactly to what you stated that you need:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sportjefit_user LEFT OUTER JOIN vriend ON sportjefit_user.id=vriend.vriend2
  where !(vriend1=48 or vriend2=48) 
  or (vfriend1 is null and vfriend2 is null);
```

Comment: I tried this but this returns values which have '48'. I want to select the values where neither vriend1 or vriend2 equals 48. I can't select using `is NULL` because these fields might be filled up at some point.

Comment: so you mean where vfriend1!=48 AND vfriend2!=48

Comment: you could also try !(vfriend1=48 or vfriend2=48)

Comment: that could be because of the data? if the data that you are using is what you have above you do not have any records where the values are non-null and one value is not 48

Comment: What if I also want to select the users where there are NULL values then? :(

Comment: try where !(vfriend1=48 or vfriend2=48) or (vfriend1 is null and vfriend2 is null)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM sportjefit_user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vriend ON sportjefit_user.id = vriend.vriend2
WHERE vriend1 <> 48
OR vriend2 <> 48
```

Or if you wanted to ensure that neither field was 48

```
SELECT * FROM sportjefit_user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vriend ON sportjefit_user.id = vriend.vriend2
WHERE vriend1 <> 48
AND vriend2 <> 48
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sportjefit_user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vriend 
ON sportjefit_user.id = vriend.vriend2
WHERE ((vriend.vriend1<>48) AND (vriend.vriend2<>48))
```

Comment: This returns values where either vriend1 or vriend2 isn't 48.. I want to select the values where neither of them are equal to 48. What I get now is.. for example: vriend1= 51, vriend2 = 48 or another example, vriend1 = 48 vriend2 = 89

Comment: @Seeger Mattijs: sorry, I didn't understand. So, do you need all the records where neither vriend1 is 48 nor vriend2 is 48? So, I think you could change `OR` with `AND`. Let me know if this is what you need...

Comment: this did it: !(vfriend1=48 or vfriend2=48) or (vfriend1 is null and vfriend2 is null)